# How would i convert this specific date string to type NSDate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How would I convert this specific date in `String`, `"2016-06-29T23:00:00-07:00"`, to an `NSDate`.

Currently I am looking at this website (http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) at the `NSDate` Formatting Table but I still can't convert the string to an `NSDate` successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let yourDate = "2016-06-29T23:00:00-07:00" //Your date in string.
let dates = NSDateFormatter()
dates.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
if let someVar = dates.dateFromString(yourDate){
print(someVar) //to avoid optional date.
}
```

Comment: Additionally, if you are developing for iOS 10, you can use the new [`NSISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsiso8601dateformatter) to encode and decode this.